# Extracting repetitions through regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to extract some useful data from a large chunck of data given through regex.
Sample string:

```
test 1:
hello op1 yviphf
hello op2 vipqwe
test 2:
hello op3
hello op4 vipgt
hello op5 zcv
```

Above contains 2 test numbers but there are several. I want to extract op1, op2, op3, op4, op5 and also the corresponding test numbers. The number of op's in each test can vary.
Below is the pattern I tried writing but it does not help:

```
test\s(\d+).*?(?:hello\s+(\S+).*?\n)+
```

The output could be list of list. The main list would have the first element as the test number and the second element might be the list containing all the op's.

Comment: Do it in two steps: first match complete sections then for each section match the op values.

Comment: Do you NEED to use regex?

Comment: Are you looking for the `/s` flag? See https://regex101.com/r/nU8aA5/1

Comment: Would [this](https://ideone.com/lCCeKw) do?

Comment: @HamZa got your point..stribizhev gave example for the same. Thanks!

Comment: @Jan it doesn't give what I want, gives only last 'op'

Comment: @tglaria there is no compulsion of using regex. Can you suggest anything better?

Comment: @stribizhev thanks, it was of great help.

Comment: You should give a better example string (more realistic) because it's hard to answer. *(how really looks ops, does the word "hello" start each line?)*. if you have a lot of data, working line by line is better, and perhaps you can avoid the regex and obtain a faster result.

Comment: If the format is fixed (always hello, space, opNUMBER, something), then you could get away with for loops, string split, and comparisons.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte thanks for your comments

Comment: @tglaria thank you, the output is mostly fixed so I think I can work with loops

Comment: @user3379410: thanks to answer the questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a 3-step approach based on regexes.

- First, get all the test numbers with `r'test\s*(\d+)'` and `re.findall` (that will only fetch a list of numbers as the `\d+` subpattern is inside a capturing group)
- Second, split the input string with `test\s*\d+` regex to obtain the subsections with `hello` codes and run the `hello\s+(\S+)` (or `(?m)^hello\s*(\S+)` if the `hello` starts at the line start) regex on each non-empty chunk (again, `re.findall` will only fetch the `\S+` submatches as it is enclosed in a capture group)
- Merge the lists into a list of tuples.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/3Ioau9):

```
import re
test_str = "test 1:\nhello op1 yviphf\nhello op2 vipqwe\ntest 2:\nhello op3\nhello op4 vipgt\nhello op5 zcv"
res1 = [y for y in re.findall(r'test\s*(\d+)', test_str) if y]
res2 = [re.findall(r'(?m)^hello\s*(\S+)', b) for b in re.split(r'test\s*\d+', test_str) if b]
print(zip(res1, res2))
```

Result: `[('1', ['op1', 'op2']), ('2', ['op3', 'op4', 'op5'])]`

Answer (score 1):

Do you NEED to use REGEX?

If not, you could get away with loops, strin comparison and splits:

```
data = {}
key = '_'
for linea in text.split('\n'):
    if "test" in linea:
        key = linea.split()[1][:-1]
        data[key]=[]
    else:
        _data_ = linea.split()[1]
        data[key].append(_data_)

print data
> {'1': ['op1', 'op2'], '2': ['op3', 'op4', 'op5']}
```